# Javascript Complete Amateur?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function I wrote to append a select box to a radiobutton set based on which radio button is clicked. It does this when one clicks one or the other. The problem is, I'm such an amateur that I can't get it to stop adding new select elements to the span I set to place them in. I keep trying different ways to check if the element or its innerHtml have been set and then use that check to decide whether to create another select. None of this has worked for me. Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial for this (i've been searching, tried nearly everything, no fez which makes me think its a simpler problem with the structure of the whole function).

Here is the code, any light shed on this would be SUPER helpful. I just taught myself to code so I know this is horrible. Thanks for the help!!

```
function moreInput(vInput)  {
var moreD = document.getElementById('moreD');
//document.write(moreD);
    if(vInput == \"approved\")  {
        if(moreD.length > 0)    {
            moreD.removeChild(approvedOpts);
        }
        var select = document.createElement(\"select\");
        select.options[0] = new Option('a');
        select.options[1] = new Option('b');
        select.options[2] = new Option('c');
        select.setAttribute(\"name\",\"approvedOptsA\");
    }
    if(vInput == \"denied\")    {
        //alert(moreD.innerHtml);
        //if(moreD.innerHtml === 'undefined')   {
            //moreD.removeChild(approvedOptsD);
            var select = document.createElement(\"select\");
            select.options[0] = new Option('x');
            select.options[1] = new Option('y');
            select.options[2] = new Option('z');
            select.setAttribute(\"id\",\"approvedOptsD\");
            select.
        //}
    }
moreD.appendChild(select);
```

}

Comment: Maybe you could remove the unnecessary backslashes to make this easier to read? Even for yourself, don't `echo` a long Javascript string, just write it directly into your HTML or a .js file. No escaping of `"` needed.

Comment: my bad, all of the html/front end stuff is output by PHP. Just put the function in a separate js file for simplification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all elements before you add any new elements.

This code should work:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

function moreInput(vInput)  {
    var moreD = document.getElementById('moreD');
        if(vInput == \"approved\")  {
            removeAllChildrens(moreD);
            var select = document.createElement(\"select\");
            select.options[0] = new Option('Comped Table');
            select.options[1] = new Option('Comped Drink');
            select.options[2] = new Option('Comped Cover');
            select.setAttribute(\"name\",\"approvedOptsA\");
        }
        if(vInput == \"denied\")    {
                removeAllChildrens(moreD);
                var select = document.createElement(\"select\");
                select.options[0] = new Option('Need to Reserve Table');
                select.options[1] = new Option('At Capacity');
                select.options[2] = new Option('Private Event');
                select.setAttribute(\"id\",\"approvedOptsD\");
        }
    moreD.appendChild(select);
}

function removeAllChildrens(cell) {
    if ( cell.hasChildNodes() ) {
        while ( cell.childNodes.length >= 1 ) {
            cell.removeChild( cell.firstChild );       
        } 
    }
}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only ever append new selects, you need to delete the old one before appending a new one.  Try the below code (I've removed your commented lines):

```
function moreInput(vInput)  {
    var moreD = document.getElementById('moreD');
    if(vInput == "approved")  {
        if(moreD.length > 0)    {
            moreD.removeChild(approvedOpts);
        }
        var select = document.createElement("select");
        select.options[0] = new Option('a');
        select.options[1] = new Option('b');
        select.options[2] = new Option('c');
        select.setAttribute("name","approvedOptsA");
    }
    if(vInput == "denied")    {
        var select = document.createElement("select");
        select.options[0] = new Option('x');
        select.options[1] = new Option('y');
        select.options[2] = new Option('z');
        select.setAttribute("id","approvedOptsD");

    }
moreD.removeChild(document.getElementById("approvedOptsD"));
moreD.removeChild(document.getElementById("approvedOptsA"));
moreD.appendChild(select);
```

It may throw some warnings, I haven't tested it but you should get the idea of what you are looking for.

[This](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-remove-elements-reprise/) is and old but still accurate and useful article on adding and removing dom nodes dynamically with javascript.